# Webmatrix: Passing a variable to an SQL query

Tags: javascript, sql, forms, razor, webmatrix-3

I've created a site in Webmatrix (cshtml) which uses a loop to display data from an SQL CE table. I have a button which when clicked runs a query to update the 'read' status of that record.
I'm having trouble passing the record ID to the query. It works if I set a static ID but when I make the ID dynamic it looks like it is working (and an Alert shows the ID is passing to a variable), but the record doesn't update.

My SQL is:

```
    db.Execute("UPDATE MyTable SET Status='F' WHERE MyTable.MyID=@0", myVar);
```

And my HTML is (@details. is the record set created for the loop):

```
    <form method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-link pull-right" name="optFlag" onclick="javascript:setStatus(@details.MyID)" ><span class="fa fa-flag"></span></button>
    </form>
```

The JS code I'm using to pass the ID as onclick is:

```
    <script>
     function setStatus(myVar) {
     }
    </script>
```

Please can someone tell me if I am on the right track and if so what am I doing wrong. If I'm completely off track what is the best way to achieve this?

Many thanks 
(PS - please let me know by comment/message if this post doesn't meet proper standards so that I can amend without negative score).

Comment: how are you passing the value of myVar from your setStatus method to your server ? who is calling the code `db.Execute(` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The button is contained within <form> and when it submits it checks through conditions to execute the relevant query.

        if( Request.Form["optFlag"] != null) {
        db.Execute("UPDATE MyTable SET Status='F' WHERE MyTable.MyID=@0", myVar); }

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your approach.  When a page is loaded, the scripting language (razor C#) will execute FIRST before the javascript ever does.  So it is impossible to make javascript execute a db call in this way.

You could instead have the javascript load a new page, send the variable to that new page in a querystring or via a form, and then use the value to execute a db call via your razor C# code.